# AWS Athena is creating an extra empty row per result

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have 4 JSONs stored in an S3 bucket which I'm using to populate a table in Athena; however when I query all (`select * from [table_name];`, an extra empty row is created for each of these JSONs. I was wondering why this happens, and if I can prevent this (beyond appending `where [column_name] is not null;` to all my queries :)).

NB the use of individual JSONs is deliberate (though I'm new to Athena, so it may be ill-advised) as I am trying to get past some issues with concurrency

See the attached images for reference[image]

[image]

I was wondering whether it was because of hidden metadata or similar files in S3, but can't find any reason that this would be the case

Comment: Are your files using CRLF between lines, or just CR? Open with a clever text editor, or even a hex editor, to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternating blank line suggests that your source file is in `CRLF` format (causing to 'new lines') rather than `CR` format.

You can test this by loading the source file into a modern text editor (eg Visual Studio Code) and changing the line-end format (often via a control in the bottom-right).

Windows tends to use `CRLF`, while other systems just use `CR`.

For some fun history, see: [Carriage return - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)